# How can I find if a iso 8601 time is within an hour range?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am making a javascript calendar and I am trying to find if a `iso 8601` string falls within an hour range, but not having much luck.  I have an array of appointments.  Each appointment has a startTime which is an `iso 8601` string.  I am then trying to use `moment` to compare if the string is between a specific hour range.  The hour is just an `int` that is being passed in, ie `1, 2, 3, 4, ...`.  Here is my code:

```
        function(appts, hour) {
           var current = appts.forEach(function(appt) {
             return moment(appt.startTime).isBetween(hour, hour + 1, 'hour');
           });
           return current;
        }
```

I am not fixated on using moment. What is the way to accomplish this task?

Comment: What is `hour` in the above? Just a number, 0-23? A `Date` instance containing a date and time? A `moment` instance containing a date and time?

Comment: It is a number.  `1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `hour` is a number as you've indicated, then you just compare `.hour()` to your target hour:

```
function(appts, hour) {
   var current = appts.forEach(function(appt) {
     return moment(appt.startTime).hour() == hour;
   });
   return current;
}
```

...assuming your `hour` starts with `0` for midnight and continues through `23` for 11 p.m., and assuming your `hour` and the datetime string are in the same timezone. If they aren't, you'll have to adjust one or the other for the timezone difference. If your `hour` is in UTC, you can easily do that by just calling [`utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) on the Moment instance:

```
function(appts, hour) {
   var current = appts.forEach(function(appt) {
     return moment(appt.startTime).utc().hour() == hour;
     // Change -------------------^^^^^^
   });
   return current;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the date strings to JavaScript objects then compare them.

```js
var dateRangeStart = new Date('2015-01-29T12:00:00');  
var dateRangeEnd = new Date('2015-01-29T13:00:00');
var testDate = new Date('2015-01-29T12:30:00');

snippet.log("Range start: " + dateRangeStart.toISOString());
snippet.log("Range end:   " + dateRangeEnd.toISOString());
snippet.log("Test date:   " + testDate.toISOString());

if(dateRangeStart < testDate && testDate < dateRangeEnd){
    snippet.log('Test date IS in range');
} else {
    snippet.log('Test date is NOT in range');
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Beware `new Date('2015-01-29T12:00:00')`, for two reasons: 1. The format wasn't added to JavaScript until ES5 (2009), so older browsers usually don't support it. 2. In ES5, they defined that leaving off the timezone indicator implied GMT, which is contrary to ISO-8601. Which is bad enough, but now the ES6 spec is trying to change that to match ISO-8601. Net result? If you don't include the timezone indicator, heaven only knows whether it'll be interpreted as local time or GMT, even on engines that understand it.